# Hook Wordpress Pingback action to perform some operation

Tags: php, wordpress, pingback

I have been trying to hook **pingback_post** action to perform some functionality (send a custom email to wp admin) whenever a pingback/linkback has been added on my wp post.

I dont know why the documentation is not available anymore on WP official page here:

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Comment.2C_Ping.2C_and_Trackback_Actions

I am using following code in my functions.php file but its not working:

```
add_action('pingback_post','pingback_inserted',100,1);
function pingback_inserted($comment_id) {    
    wp_mail( get_option('admin_email'), 'Ping added', 'Ping added');        
}
```